# Visual studio code cannot open project successfully

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, msbuild

When I try to load a project, it shows the following error message and I still can view the C# code. However, F12 (Go to Definition) does not work anymore. I am still curious why this situation happens.

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Build.Logging.BinaryLogger' from assembly 'Microsoft.Build,
>   Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath)    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath,
>   ProjectLoader loader)    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String
>   projectFilePath, Func`1 loader)

Comment: do you run VScode on Windows? if using Mono, try reinstall it.